# Is it possible to pause punput listener thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pynput

I have a Python script that reads keyboard user inputs, and if a certain key is pressed, pynput emulates the press of other specified keys.
The problem is that when the keys are emulated, pynput recognizes them as user input and the function gets stuck in a loop.
So, pynput emulates the key press and also reacts to that key press.
Is it possible to pause listener thread while the function is being executed?

**Here is the code**

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller, Listener, KeyCode
from pynput import mouse, keyboard
from loguru import logger


kb = Controller()

ENGINE: bool = False
WEAPONS: bool = False
SYSTEM: bool = False


def engine() -> None:
    kb.press(Key.down)
    kb.release(Key.down)
    kb.press(Key.right)
    kb.release(Key.right)
    kb.press(Key.right)
    kb.release(Key.right)
    kb.press(Key.left)
    kb.release(Key.left)
    kb.press(Key.right)
    kb.release(Key.right)

def system() -> None:
    pass

def weapons() -> None:
    pass

def default() -> None:
    kb.press(Key.down)
    kb.release(Key.down)



def toggle_event(key) -> None:
    global ENGINE, SYSTEM, WEAPONS

    if key == KeyCode(char='w') or key == KeyCode(char='a') or key == KeyCode(char='s') or key == KeyCode(char='d') and engine is not True:
        try:
            ENGINE = True
            SYSTEM = False
            WEAPONS = False
            engine()
            logger.success("SWITCHED TO ENGINES")

        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(f"CANNOT SWITCH TO DEFAULT: \n{e}")



    elif key == keyboard.Key.down:
        try:
            ENGINE = False
            SYSTEM = False
            WEAPONS = False
            default()
            logger.success("SWITCHED TO DEFAULT")

        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(f"CANNOT SWITCH TO DEFAULT: \n{e}")




    elif key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        listener.stop()

    else:
        if type(key) is keyboard.Key:
            print(f'Клавиша {key}: код {key.value.vk}')
        elif type(key) is keyboard.KeyCode:
            print(f'Клавиша {key}: код {key.vk}')

with Listener(on_press=toggle_event) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

pay attention to the default() func.
When I press the down arrow, the default() function is triggered, which emulates pressing the down arrow. However, the listener also responds to these emulations and restarts the default() function.
Therefore, I need to pause the thread (if possible) while the default() function or any other function is being executed.

Comment: The [documentation](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has the answer to your question.